# Docker is getting stopped after creating the cron image

Tags: php, cron, dockerfile

I am trying to build the docker image of cron with supersonic which can fetch the logs from my apache server and run the container but it's failing Can anyone help me in this to fix the issue as cron container is getting stopped it's not getting up

Here is the docker file

```html
FROM php:7.4 as cron
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron
#Run the echo
RUN echo "* * * * * root php /var/www/artisan schedule:run >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1" >> /etc/crontab
USER root
ENV SUPERCRONIC_URL=https://github.com/aptible/supercronic/releases/download/v0.1.12/supercronic-linux-amd64 \
    SUPERCRONIC=supercronic-linux-amd64 \
    SUPERCRONIC_SHA1SUM=048b95b48b708983effb2e5c935a1ef8483d9e3e
RUN curl -fsSLO "$SUPERCRONIC_URL" \
 && echo "${SUPERCRONIC_SHA1SUM}  ${SUPERCRONIC}" | sha1sum -c - \
 && chmod +x "$SUPERCRONIC" \
 && mv "$SUPERCRONIC" "/usr/local/bin/${SUPERCRONIC}" \
 && ln -s "/usr/local/bin/${SUPERCRONIC}" /usr/local/bin/supercronic
#Create the log file to be able to run taild
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
EXPOSE 9000
CMD bash -c "cron && php-fpm"
```

And here is the docker log of the container

```
[
{
    "Id": "54ad1fc4a8f2e5be65ffad5084cb6f1da2db5255f6211f6302cd06ebb8915931",
    "Created": "2022-01-25T08:04:20.065641695Z",
    "Path": "docker-php-entrypoint",
    "Args": [
        "/bin/sh",
        "-c",
        "bash -c \"cron && php\""
    ],
    "State": {
        "Status": "exited",
        "Running": false,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 0,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2022-01-25T08:04:20.817610984Z",
        "FinishedAt": "2022-01-25T08:04:20.95033829Z"
    },
    "Image": "sha256:3dd61d4ae8f4991451882c28be21843c5f8a3742cf7faa8c20f8fa680a9ffdef",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/54ad1fc4a8f2e5be65ffad5084cb6f1da2db5255f6211f6302cd06ebb8915931/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/54ad1fc4a8f2e5be65ffad5084cb6f1da2db5255f6211f6302cd06ebb8915931/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/54ad1fc4a8f2e5be65ffad5084cb6f1da2db5255f6211f6302cd06ebb8915931/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/54ad1fc4a8f2e5be65ffad5084cb6f1da2db5255f6211f6302cd06ebb8915931/54ad1fc4a8f2e5be65ffad5084cb6f1da2db5255f6211f6302cd06ebb8915931-json.log",
    "Name": "/cron",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "overlay2",
    "Platform": "linux",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
    "ExecIDs": null,
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": [
            "/home/devops/Desktop/manas/public_html:/var/www/public_html:rw"
        ],
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "NetworkMode": "manas_manas-network",
        "PortBindings": {},
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "AutoRemove": false,
        "VolumeDriver": "",
        "VolumesFrom": [],
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "CgroupnsMode": "host",
        "Dns": null,
        "DnsOptions": null,
        "DnsSearch": null,
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "IpcMode": "private",
        "Cgroup": "",
        "Links": null,
        "OomScoreAdj": 0,
        "PidMode": "",
        "Privileged": false,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "UTSMode": "",
        "UsernsMode": "",
        "ShmSize": 67108864,
        "Runtime": "runc",
        "ConsoleSize": [
            0,
            0
        ],
        "Isolation": "",
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "Memory": 0,
        "NanoCpus": 0,
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
        "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "Devices": null,
        "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
        "DeviceRequests": null,
        "KernelMemory": 0,
        "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "MemorySwappiness": null,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "PidsLimit": null,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "CpuCount": 0,
        "CpuPercent": 0,
        "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
        "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
        "MaskedPaths": [
            "/proc/asound",
            "/proc/acpi",
            "/proc/kcore",
            "/proc/keys",
            "/proc/latency_stats",
            "/proc/timer_list",
            "/proc/timer_stats",
            "/proc/sched_debug",
            "/proc/scsi",
            "/sys/firmware"
        ],
        "ReadonlyPaths": [
            "/proc/bus",
            "/proc/fs",
            "/proc/irq",
            "/proc/sys",
            "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
        ]
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Data": {
            "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d962aede310211a036c98df22dd6a835523bf0281cc8169f0541eab47aa5adec-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4c854b5c4204d084d52892e47d1f3234d23ebb74cfd12ee39f3b326be98d6583/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/dbf9ab098782c99d35de82887ee23004f83984f348aff4f965ab7d0e211123d3/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a085dc25c6b777242861c1630e842c20bf3f7de01d556cb4d55209761478e08f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0bf515800b5ef39f5de565dba17d1d3f06e9e4cb67991fc653f6101a2df5c36c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9407a08845446d90604285c20222f7f814f63f2a1701bae2062ea0334925e1a7/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1b1133bad0c0f87c3b37dc73dac7fe12eff9e07739578086088d267fc98b4969/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/66a4a4176ab19a57e7e1c78caa4364e908ecb0d38f5db67513812e7d07fc706e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b30fda3e81492607b600b41a798be86876097e085936c6a5c7372e8eb6425349/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/818268870f639651111fe7f3d3a5481d4de0edc9c6f34b9f64c6290fff40b07f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d9b131a954e8449b30aadf95e3f9d48eecf1cb95b13de7b41b47d03fe410e28c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/dd5da1b51e4f16e72e2a914177030a983541939359099dea9b44668e93ed45b4/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2dcb838422d61a2bac37a9bd76c73d71448ffbbe58b9bf0f8380ee39f6fae41f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e491672686906fda7602592c9dee0079970320e9c03e6f4492b739e1bb8e2ff2/diff",
            "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d962aede310211a036c98df22dd6a835523bf0281cc8169f0541eab47aa5adec/merged",
            "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d962aede310211a036c98df22dd6a835523bf0281cc8169f0541eab47aa5adec/diff",
            "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d962aede310211a036c98df22dd6a835523bf0281cc8169f0541eab47aa5adec/work"
        },
        "Name": "overlay2"
    },
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/home/devops/Desktop/manas/public_html",
            "Destination": "/var/www/public_html",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        }
    ],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "54ad1fc4a8f2",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "root",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "9000/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "PHPIZE_DEPS=autoconf \t\tdpkg-dev \t\tfile \t\tg++ \t\tgcc \t\tlibc-dev \t\tmake \t\tpkg-config \t\tre2c",
            "PHP_INI_DIR=/usr/local/etc/php",
            "PHP_CFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64",
            "PHP_CPPFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64",
            "PHP_LDFLAGS=-Wl,-O1 -pie",
            "GPG_KEYS=42670A7FE4D0441C8E4632349E4FDC074A4EF02D 5A52880781F755608BF815FC910DEB46F53EA312",
            "PHP_VERSION=7.4.27",
            "PHP_URL=https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.4.27.tar.xz",
            "PHP_ASC_URL=https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.4.27.tar.xz.asc",
            "PHP_SHA256=3f8b937310f155822752229c2c2feb8cc2621e25a728e7b94d0d74c128c43d0c",
            "SUPERCRONIC_URL=https://github.com/aptible/supercronic/releases/download/v0.1.12/supercronic-linux-amd64",
            "SUPERCRONIC=supercronic-linux-amd64",
            "SUPERCRONIC_SHA1SUM=048b95b48b708983effb2e5c935a1ef8483d9e3e"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "/bin/sh",
            "-c",
            "bash -c \"cron && php\""
        ],
        "Image": "manas_cron",
        "Volumes": {
            "/var/www/public_html": {}
        },
        "WorkingDir": "",
        "Entrypoint": [
            "docker-php-entrypoint"
        ],
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "ecf1880bebf07b65becbe0d7f4feab7cfaaea3ce484d7628ca1c16d1f01ce3a9",
            "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
            "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "manas",
            "com.docker.compose.project.config_files": "docker-compose.yml",
            "com.docker.compose.project.working_dir": "/home/devops/Desktop/manas",
            "com.docker.compose.service": "cron",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.29.2"
        }
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "3a3f85e18d3be9d8484bc493fb9e5c21b105179434660bb4bf00eb77da939227",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {},
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/3a3f85e18d3b",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "",
        "Gateway": "",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "",
        "IPPrefixLen": 0,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "",
        "Networks": {
            "manas_manas-network": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": [
                    "cron",
                    "54ad1fc4a8f2"
                ],
                "NetworkID": "bfa2edf94c717f1985dd382d1f808b17a8d16710b8ab066d83779acf109c68a4",
                "EndpointID": "",
                "Gateway": "",
                "IPAddress": "",
                "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "",
                "DriverOpts": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

]

Comment: Also posted on https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-is-getting-stopped-after-creating-the-image/120280

Answer (score 0):

As you are running supercronic on top of the container, You need to inspect your docker image and override your entry point to start your php image and supercronic.

It might get conflicted in the startup and your supercron may potential to fail in the startup.

```
     Docker entry:
     ENTRYPOINT  /var/user/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

You can create the entrypoint file and start the both the entries with supercron first.

Comment: I tried the same Imran but still, I am getting the same error